# check if circle is hovered HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to make a hover state for circle in canvas. Here's what I've got

Code:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let circle = { x: 100, y: 100, r: 30 } 

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
ctx.strokeStyle = "#aaa"
ctx.lineWidth = 3
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath()


this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

    let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    let position = {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y:  e.clientY - rect.top,
    }
    
    if(position.x > circle.x - circle.r &&
        position.x < circle.x + circle.r &&
        position.y < circle.y + circle.r &&
        position.y > circle.y - circle.r ) {
            this.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    } else {
        this.canvas.style.cursor = 'default'
    }

})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

But in above code, it will hover as if the circle is a square.

[image]

It will apply the hover state outside the circle, in the every corner of square. I think it is because of the if conditions in this piece of code:

```js
if(position.x > circle.x - circle.r &&
    position.x < circle.x + circle.r &&
    position.y < circle.y + circle.r &&
    position.y > circle.y - circle.r ) {
        this.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer'
}
```

Does anyone have solution to make the hover state is working exactly inside circle?

Comment: Because a canvas is always a quadrilateral.

Comment: @mstephen19 is there any way to get the circle size instead of square?